# How to retrieve latest build from Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Our shop uses Visual Studio Team Services, previously Visual Studio Online, for SVN and Builds.

We are trying to find a way to download the drop package (build zip) via the command line. For this purpose, we stumbled upon [TFS Drop Downloader](http://chocolatey.org/packages/TfsDropDownloader) which appears to be made for this very reason. Unfortunately, the last revision was made in 2013 and does not appear to work with Visual Studio Team Services anymore. When we supply the parameters (collection, username, password, etc.) it asks again for credentials via a Windows dialog and all attempts seem to fail.

Is there another way to download the builds from Visual Studio Team Services via the command line?

Sample command line:

`C:\> tfsdropdownloader /c:https://project.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /t:"Project Name" /b:"Build Definition" /u:username /p:password`

Even though we supply username and password, the tool asks for credentials again via a Windows dialog and fails even when supplied.

Comment: Have you setup your VSO account for [alternate credentials](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/share-your-eclipse-projects-vs.aspx)?

Comment: Yup, I just did it again with another admin account. I read reports that some special characters needed to be escaped in the password, but even that did not work. Still no luck.

Comment: Looking into the source code of the tool, it looks like it gets stuck on `collection.EnsureAuthenticated()` within the `Authenticate` method.

Comment: I just tried authenticating from Win8.1 to my VSO account using LinqPad against the API, and I don't need alternate credentials.

Comment: I will try from my home computer after work. I wonder if this is somehow related to security options / firewall. I appreciate your help Dave.

Comment: It appears to be working from my home computer. Must be some sort of permissions/security issue.